# jquery mobile preventing replaceWith div update?

Tags: jquery, mobile, replacewith

I have a working shopping cart system in which items are added to the shopping cart via jquery ajax calls, and a div on the requesting page is updated using `replaceWith` to reflect the number of items and amount.  It works great. (Incidentally, this div appears in the header of every page).

I'm now working on a jquery mobile (Alpha 4) version.  Items get added to the shoppingcart, but the div in question is no longer updated.  The particular code that isn't working is:

```
$("#cartsummary").replaceWith(html);
```

I would really appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I figured it out.  JQM adds successive pages to the existing DOM, wrapping each in an id, so that pressing the back button doesn't require a page load.  This means that there can be several copies of my "cartsummary" id on a page.  That obviously wouldn't work.  I changed the id to an class, and it worked.